# Is Golang's ... syntax really just varargs?

Tags: go, pointers, parameters

Well, I have a simple example, although it may seem pointless, but these examples have deviated greatly from my cognition.

Can anyone tell me what happened.

I pass the elements in []int to the parameter args with the ... syntax, but when I change the formal parameter args, the []int actual parameter is changed.

I modified the ordering of args , but the ordering of []int is also affected:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func bubbleSort(args ...int) {
    for i := 0; i < len(args); i++ {
        for j := 0; j < len(args)-1; j++ {
            if args[j] > args[j+1] {
                args[j], args[j+1] = args[j+1], args[j]
            }
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    isle := []int{3, 6, 1, 2, 5}
    bubbleSort(isle...)

    fmt.Printf("%v\n", isle)
}

// [1 2 3 5 6]
```

What if I pass in a single parameter? Apparently []int is not affected by args:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func bubbleSort(args ...int) {
    for i := 0; i < len(args); i++ {
        for j := 0; j < len(args)-1; j++ {
            if args[j] > args[j+1] {
                args[j], args[j+1] = args[j+1], args[j]
            }
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    isle := []int{3, 6, 1, 2, 5}
    bubbleSort(isle[0], isle[1], isle[2], isle[3], isle[4])

    fmt.Printf("%v\n", isle)
}

// [3 6 1 2 5]
```

Comment: See the [specification](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Passing_arguments_to_..._parameters).  In the first example,  `isle` is passed to the function. The function modifies the `isle`'s backing array. In the second example, a new slice with backing array is passed to the function.

Comment: @CeriseLimón Good answer, solved my doubts. It's really confusing ..

Comment: Variadic functions are really just functions that take a slice as the final argument, with a syntactic shortcut to construct the slice at the call-site.

Comment: In golang - if you send slice somewhere - you haven't think that it cannot be changed.

Answer (score 1):

Golang is not about "variable safety" as Rust. So you shoud never think that slice sent to function will not be corrupted.

If you want to use variadic functions but send slices, copy it:

```
func myUnsafeFunc(args ...int) { 
   // it will change args
}
func wantToSaveSliceFunc() {
   myLovingSlice := []int{1,2,3}
   myUnsafeFunc(append([]int(nil), slice...)...)
}
```

https://freshman.tech/snippets/go/copy-slices/

It's not confusing if you remember that `spread operator ...`  is just a shugar .

Do not use it in your own API without serious reasone (as in fmt.Printf(...) for example) prefer use of explicit `x []type` notation over `x ...type`:

```
func myUnsafeFunc(args []int) { 
   // it will change args
}
func wantToSaveSliceFunc() {
   myLovingSlice := []int{1,2,3}
   myUnsafeFunc(append([]int(nil), slice...))
}
```

it still requires copying of slice, but it's much clear by semantics